# FQL friends photos - empty

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

Hey... I try to get my friend's photos.

FB login button code:

```
<fb:login-button show-faces="true" width="200" max-rows="1" perms="user_photos,friends_photos,user_photo_video_tags,friends_photo_video_tags"></fb:login-button>
```

FQL query (uid is user ID):

```
SELECT pid, aid, owner, src, src_small, created FROM photo WHERE aid IN (SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner="+uid+") ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 30
```

Why in some cases I get no photos? If I see my friend's profile I can see he has 100+ photos but the request is saying no. I would like to get 10 random images for friend with uid=X.

Thanks for tips.`enter code here`

Comment: I'm having a is liar issue, but with link objects. http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8222516/trying-to-read-friends-links-in-facebook-using-fql-why-do-some-friends-return-a

Comment: Did you ever find out what was going on?

Comment: I guess those friends do not allow sharing photos with friends of friends. Having similar issue.

Comment: check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12956181/getting-latest-photos-from-friends-not-working